# want to change a code of ( Cells.Find(What:="28513" ) to Cells.Find(What:="textbox1.value" in a form

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

this is the code i use by macro i want to change the "28513" to textbox1 and "1509" to textbox2
can u please advice

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Cells.Find(What:="28513", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.Find(What:="28537", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="28537", Replacement:="1509", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Find(What:="28537", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i reach to a solution and gonna share with the community

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Cells.Find(What:=TextBox1.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:=TextBox1.Value, Replacement:=TextBox2.Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    

End Sub
```